# Generating a line chart with data over a 10 days but displaying by hours rather than by days

Tags: excel, charts

I'm trying to generate a chart in Excel. My problem is, that the chart is being generated by days and not by hours. This is why on the 12th October there's only "a spike" visible and not an actual change of the value.

[image]

Data:

```
07.10.2018 16:01   53,00
12.10.2018 10:31   53,00
12.10.2018 11:31   61,00
12.10.2018 13:31   61,00
12.10.2018 14:31   59,00
12.10.2018 17:31   59,00
12.10.2018 18:31   53,00
16.10.2018 11:31   53,00
```

Comment: The main problem is you are using a line chart while your data is not continuous. So unless you want to treat the missing values (for the hours in between your measurements) as the same as the last measurement I'd say you don't use a line chart in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact, that the question was not well received, I want to post the solution. With the help of Chrisvdberge, I've found the way how to generate an appropriate chart - Scatter with Straight Lines:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To create a chart for this data you have to create a bar chart yourself (by manually selecting the data range and axis range) (i am saying bar chart as bar chart is better suited for such data, a line chart is used to show continuity which is not the case here). if you try to create an automatic chart it will not be correct (as you have already seen).

It depends upon the version you are using but if i could simplify the points that can be applicable to all version these can be the steps.

1. insert an empty bar chart
2. Add the data values by adding data series and selecting your values in right side column
3. Add an x axis series by adding or editing the x axis series and selecting the values in left hand side column
4. if excel converts that series to an auto incremented series you have to format the x axis by right clicking on it and press something similar to format axis
5. Now convert that series to text values rather then automatic values.

You can also insert an automatic chart as you have already done and after that try to perform the above points from point 4.